# Show dofollow on homepage but hide on subpage

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, footer, nofollow

Using WordPress, I have two links in my Footer Widget.
One is a dofollow link and other is a nofollow link.

I need to display the dofollow on the homepage only, while the nofollow needs to be displayed on every subpage.

I’m wondering if this is possible with CSS, or if I need to use JQuery.

I’ve tried using the below code but have achieved nothing:

```
.footer-dofollow:is(.page-id-123) { display: none; }
```

```
.footer-nofollow:not(.page-id-123) { display: none; }
```

Any advice or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you editing the theme .php files? If so, you can use some functions to check if it is home or a different page.

Answer (score 1):

Since the page-id class is shown on body element usually, in CSS you can try this:

```
.page-id-123 .footer-dofollow {
  display: none;
}
.footer-dofollow {
  display: none;
}
.page-id-123 .footer-dofollow {
  display: inline;
}
```

---

Other way to make it is editing the widget .php file and checking if it is home page or not using `is_home()` function.

```
<?php if (is_home()): ?>
  <a href="example.com" class="footer-dofollow">Link</alt>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (!is_home()): ?>
  <a href="example.com" class="footer-nofollow">Link</alt>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

You can also try to use `is_front_page()`.

```
<?php if (is_front_page()): ?>
  <a href="example.com" class="footer-dofollow">Link</alt>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (!is_front_page()): ?>
  <a href="example.com" class="footer-nofollow">Link</alt>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So I've tried the following but I'm served the NoFollow link on all pages including the homepage. Any thoughts?

`
<?php if (is_home()) { ?>
    <a href="https://google.com/">DoFollow</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php if (!is_home()) { ?>
    <a href="https://google.com/" rel="nofollow">NoFollow</a>
<?php } ?>
`

Comment: Often It depends on your Wordpress config for home page. Try ``if (!is_front_page())`` instead of if ``(!is_home())``.